# Matthew 11:13: "prophesied untill John" - No prophesies after John the Baptist?

Tags: matthew, prophecy, law, john-the-baptist

> For all the prophets and the law prophesied until John (KJV, Matthew 11:13)

It looks like the phrase "until John" marks a special watermark here as if either there would be no more prophesies after John or at least their nature would be different from John the Baptist's time on. Does the original text have any of these connotations?

Comment: It has to do with authority of the prophecy , not prophecy in general , Jesus and then apostles assumed next level of revelation , ( as in our foundation is in Law , prophets, apostles)

Comment: Please see my answer to this related question:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8171/in-hebrews-12-to-what-does-the-greek-word-%CE%B1%E1%BC%B0%E1%BF%B6%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%82-refer/29384#29384

Comment: Besides heralding in the saviour of our souls, JC, no scripture was accepted into the Bible after John the Baptist’s “The Book of Revelation”. This scripture is the prime scripture of written prophecies and law.

Comment: @Constantthin - What on earth is John the Baptist’s “The Book of Revelation”?

Comment: The last book of the Bible. Authored by a name called John. It could be any person called John. John the apostle has been suggested. I think John the Baptist is a better fit. His reputation, based on Biblical prophesies, and words of Jesus, fits perfectly on him being the author. Herod, of course, would have to have secretly spared him the beheading, which was ordered by Herod's wicked queen, for this to be true. John the Baptist would then have secretly been taken to the prison island Patmos,

Comment: @Constantthin (1) "_John the Baptist would then have secretly been taken to the prison island Patmos_" – Well, to use modern British English, that’s highly unlikely. John then would have somehow given a clue in Revelation that he was exactly that John the Baptist.

Comment: @Constantthin (2) Besides, in Rev 1:9 the author says that he was sent to the island of Patmos “because of the word of God and the testimony of Jesus”. But John the Baptist was put into prison by Herod not for the testimony of Jesus. Even some time after that Herod knew nothing about Jesus: “But Herod said, “I beheaded John. Who, then, is this I hear such things about?” And he tried to see Him.” (Luke 9:9)

Comment: I see. Well, I tend not to discard any possibilities, even the ones that may presently look as unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

The verse does not say that no one prophesied after John, but rather that "*the* prophets" (οι προφηται) only prophesied up to (εως) John.  By including the reference to "the Law" (ο νομος) as well, He is clearly referring to the Old Testament "Prophets" (majuscule).  We find the same reference to "the Law and the Prophets" in Luke (16:16):

> *The Law and the Prophets were until John: since that time the Kingdom of God is preached, and every man presseth into it.*

Justin Martyr, a 2nd century Christian apologist (100-165 AD), interpreted this verse as also meaning that there would no longer be any sort of prophets among non-believing Jews:

> If the prophets had not ceased, so that there were no more in your
>   nation, Trypho, after this John, it is evident that what I say in
>   reference to Jesus Christ might be regarded perhaps as ambiguous. But
>   if John came first calling on men to repent, and Christ, while [John]
>   still sat by the river Jordan, having come, put an end to his
>   prophesying and baptizing, and preached also Himself, saying that the
>   kingdom of heaven is at hand, and that He must suffer many things from
>   the Scribes and Pharisees, and be crucified, and on the third day rise
>   again, and would appear again in Jerusalem, and would again eat and
>   drink with His disciples; and foretold that in the interval between
>   His [first and second] advent, as I previously said, priests and false
>   prophets would arise in His name, which things do actually appear;
>   then how can they be ambiguous, when you may be persuaded by the
>   facts? Moreover, He referred to the fact that there would be no longer
>   in your nation any prophet, and to the fact that men recognised how
>   that the New Testament, which God formerly announced [His intention
>   of] promulgating, was then present, i.e., Christ Himself; and in the
>   following terms: ‘The law and the prophets were until John the
>   Baptist'
>
> [*Dialog with Trypho the Jew*, Chapter LI](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf01.viii.iv.li.html)

Answer (score 3):

The verse is simply saying the law (meaning the Torah, the first 5 books of the OT where prophecies of Christ can be found) as well as the prophets (meaning the prophets of OT where prophecies of Christ can also be found) foretold of a day when the Messiah would arrive.

"until John" The ministry of the law & prophets foretelling a Messiah who was to come ceased with John. John announced, not a Messiah that was to come, but a Messiah that had come.

Comment: Succinct and precise

Answer (score 1):

The verse does not prohibit more prophesy after John the Immersor, but says that all the previous OT prophets spoke of the days of John.

"for **all** the prophets and the law **till John** did prophesy,"  (YLT)

"All" is Strong's Greek 3956 - πάντες (pantes), defined as all, every.

From Thayer's Greek Lexicon: 2 with a plural - all (the totality of the persons or things designated by the noun)

"All" meant the entirety, the whole of the prophets and the whole of the law.

"Until John" or "till John"  marked the time that "all" or the whole of the prophets had prophesied.  Christ was speaking of the OT prophets who prophesied of His coming.

The prophets had foretold of **the latter days** of the coming of the Messiah.  That they were **until John** marked John's generation as the latter days and the fulfillment of those OT prophesies in his generation - the first century A.D.

Ellicott's Commentary on Matt. 11:13,

> "(13) All the prophets and the law.—The usual order is inverted, because stress is laid on the prophetic rather than the legislative aspect of previous revelation. They did their work pointing to the kingdom of heaven in the far-off future of the latter days, **but John saw it close at hand, and proclaimed its actual appearance.**"  Source: [Biblehub](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/matthew/11-13.htm)

Gill's Exposition on same:

> "For all the prophets and the law prophesied until John. These words are to be considered in connection with Matthew 11:11 and are a further proof of John's being greater than any of the prophets; because all the inspired writers and prophets, **who were before him, prophesied of the Messiah** as to come; and either spoke of him in obscure terms, or represented him under dark shadows and figures: **whereas John spake of him as already come**, and in plain terms, and directed to his very person; and since his time, there have been no prophecies concerning the Messiah and his kingdom; vision and prophecy are now sealed up; **all which are acknowledged by the Jews themselves, who (b) say, , "all the prophets did not prophesy but to, or of the days of the Messiah".** This was the subject, and these the limits of their prophecies; for they own (c), that **"from the day that the temple was destroyed, , "prophecy was taken away from the prophets".'**'
>
> "Since that time, they confess they have had no prophet (d), and that they are not able to observe their signs.
>
> "(b) T. Bab. Beracot, fol. 34. 2. Sabbat, fol. 63. 1. Sanhedrim, fol. 99. 1.((c) T. Bava Bathra, fol. 12. 1.((d) Abarbinel in Dan. fol. 63. 4. "  Source: Ibid.

Matt. 11:13 is a time marker, a time text; and defines that generation in which Christ was manifested (1 Pet. 1:20; Heb. 1:1-3) as the generation that saw the fulfillment of all the OT prophets and of all the old covenant law.  Christ fulfilled them all.  He did not leave anything unfinished.

That generation of the first century A.D. was that generation that saw Christ walk on this earth, that saw Him crucified, that saw Him ascend into heaven.  Christ did not fail in any of the prophesies.

All of the apostles continued to prophesy of the last and final event, namely the destruction of Jerusalem and the temple, at which time His spiritual kingdom, the "promised land" (2 Pet. 3:13) was fully established.

The beloved apostle John was given the last prophesy of that destruction and told he would prophesy again (Rev. 10:11) before many peoples.  The word "again" means that the apostle John had already spent much of his time prophesying during the 40 year preaching of the gospel after the crucifixion.

The latter days were finished when the temple was destroyed in A.D. 70, at which time the law was completely fulfilled.  That was the end of the latter days, and the end of the prophesies as Gabriel foretold Daniel that his holy people would be scattered (Dan. 12:7)

We are not living in the latter, or last days.  That is why all prophesy is now sealed, and has been sealed since A.D. 70.

See the evidences from the scriptures that I have presented at my blog https://shreddingtheveil.org.  The series "It's Not The End of The World: Parts I - X" begin at the bottom margin and lay out the sequence.

John the Immersor (baptist) was not the last prophet; the beloved apostle John was the last prophet.

Comment: John the Baptist wrote the Book of Revelation after he secretly had been moved to Patmos, so noone would notice that his head had been replaced with another person, or dummy’s head.

Answer (score 0):

The Prophets, as predictors and hopers of the advent of Christ (John 5:39) have ceased, because Christ has come and how can one prophesy about the *fait accompli*? And what is the meaning of this accomplished fact? Nothing else, but that the consequences of Adam's sin, that tormented mankind, got cured through Christ - "the Second Adam from Heaven" (1 Cor. 15:45), and the enmity of mankind with God was abolished through the Incarnation of His only-begotten Son and His co-creator of the universe (John 1:1-3), and now through human co-action with His Graceful presence in human hearts, human is able to overcome the power of sin that blocked his way to the Kingdom of Heaven. This co-action with Grace in fight against sins is exactly the beatifying "violence" through which the Kingdom of Heaven is "conquered" through Christ by His followers, which was coveted by the Old Testament prophets, desired by them and dreamed about by them, but they had not it (Luke 10:24). Thus, with the advent of Christ *this category* of prophets became obsolete.

However, the Holy Spirit, who is also the Spirit of Prophecy (Rev. 19:10) of course does not cease to work in Christians and teach them, so that also among Christians there are specially gifted with this respect, who are not on the same level as apostles, but are second highest as prophets (1 Cor. 12:28). We see one of such even warned through Holy Spirit the Apostle Paul not to go to Jerusalem for he would be caught there (Acts 21:11), but Paul still went there, without violating God's commandment, for the same Spirit gave him a deeper insight than to the prophet who warned him, for Paul knew through the same Spirit that this prophesy was not to deter him from going to Jerusalem, but to make revealed for the Christians around him and this prophet himself the degree of love and devotion he had in his heart to Christ and his apostolic mission.

Thus, prophets exist also after the advent of Christ. Yet, their character is different, even if the name is the same.

Just to give a clarifying analogy: say, a man was taken by waves after a shipwreck to some remote island of the Pacific Ocean. This man teaches some of the most gifted aborigines to write and scratch letters on stones. Those aborigines are called henceforth "writers". This guy is, say, a technician, who is far from fiction-writing to say nothing about poetry, but knows that there exists this great world of literature, that expresses human psychology in a different, more refined and elevated way and he tells the aboriginal writers: "some day another man will come here who will teach you not only how to write simple ideas, but will give you insight and skill to write stories and novels, plays and verses!". Thus, the aboriginal writers know that their writing is just a preparatory for some greater tidings. And then, after hundred years, a real teacher of literature, of creative writing arrives to them and teaches them to write stories, novels, poems etc. The gifted aborigines of the island will become poets and novelists and will be still called "writers" but with quite a different significance and semantics, for now they are graced by the skills of rhetorics. Similarly, Christian prophets are still called "prophets", but with an exceedingly different semantics, for they do not prophesize about the Advent of Christ any more, but about deeper and deeper mysteries of the Kingdom of Heaven, that is already open for humanity through this Advent.

Comment: "This co-action with Grace in fight against sins is exactly the beatifying "violence" through which the Kingdom of Heaven is "conquered" through Christ by His followers, which was coveted by the Old Testament prophets" - Jesus said that the kingdom is taken by violence "from the days of John the Baptist". So, are you saying that that "beatifying violence" did not exist before John the Baptist? And why is it "from the days of John the Baptist" if John himself that the kingdom had just drawn near, that is, the kingdom was not there yet?

Comment: A good question! The "days of Baptist" means when John started to teach people that he is not the messiah, but just gives a preparatory baptism in order to lead to Him who will baptise by Holy Spirit, and John is glad when his disciples leave him to join Jesus, for that was his mission. Now, with aid of Jesus it is already possible to "conquer the Kingdom", that is to say, to inherit it, through the "violence" i.e. valiant fight against sins in us. Jesus speaks about the process that has started, that was not before, but is initiated by His Advent witnessed and  signalled  by John's preaching.

Comment: "Now, with aid of Jesus it is already possible to "conquer the Kingdom", that is to say, to inherit it, through the "violence" i.e. valiant fight against sins in us" - Following this logic, then none of the old testament patriarchs and prophets  don't get to inherit the kingdom. However, Luke 13:28 says that Abraham, and Isaac, and Jacob, and all the prophets will be in the kingdom.

Comment: They all inherit the Kingdom but only after and through the Incarnation of Word, for Jesus, the Word Incarnate is necessary for salvation of all, either living or dead (for with Him all are alive /cf. Matt 12:27/). To say that Abraham, Isaac et al had a special entry to the Kingdom without the Incarnate Word would 1) invest them with a theologically unsound privilege over the rest of humans and 2) reveal the historical Incarnation of Word unnecessary for the redemption of all mankind. Resurrected Lord enabled also the  saints of the Old Testament participate in His victory over sin and death.

Comment: (1) "To say that Abraham, Isaac et al had a special entry to the Kingdom without the Incarnate Word would invest them with a theologically unsound privilege over the rest of humans " - I didn't say that they enter the kingdom without the Incarnate Word; however, if we follow your logic of "beautifying violence", we inevitably place them into a category of those who entered the kingdom without resorting to that "beautifying violence", since Jesus said that the "beautifying violence for the kingdom" had started only at the days of John. If so, then it already amounts to a kind of privilege or

Comment: (2) , at the very least, to a different way of entering the kingdom. And the question then arises as to why some people get to the kingdom only through resorting to that "beautifying violence" while others did not have to do that? And also, why exactly that change of ways (of how humans can enter the kingdom) took place exactly in the days of John and not, say, at the day of Jesus' resurrection?

Comment: 1. There is a historical privilege of those who live after the Incarnation, because of the beatifying violence made possible by Incarnation. See infants: when they die, Christ saves them, but their glory is less than of saints who valiantly battled for Christ. So, any Christian saint is higher than prophets in their historical setting, for they were given greater degree of Grace. Yet, I do not say any Christian saint is higher than Abraham, because the Incarnate Lord crowns the latter with the similar crown for his co-action with that intensity of Grace that was available in Abraham's time.

Comment: 2.  ("why exactly that change .... .... at the day of Jesus' resurrection?") -  when Jesus says "from now on..." He means the entire process of salvation the culmination of which is of course Resurrection. It is like being poisoned with a deadly poison against which there is no remedy - it kills in a process, with a rigid logic. The same is here but other way around - coming to Jesus means that you are in a rigid process of co-suffering, co-crucifying, co-dying and co-resurrecting with Him, and not involuntarily like in case of poison, but voluntarily and with a free reciprocation with Him.

Comment: 1) ("because the Incarnate Lord crowns the latter with the similar crown for his co-action with that intensity of Grace that was available in Abraham's time") - So if the kingdom-awarding grace was available for the old testament saint Abraham - long before Christ's incarnation and resurrection - why then that kind grace was not available for all the humans living in old testament times?

Comment: 2) Also, if the kingdom-awarding grace was still possible in the OT times (in case with Abraham) and it did not require to "valiantly battle for Christ", why then was there a need to establish another kind of kingdom-awarding grace in the days of John the Baptist (that is, the grace that also gave the entrance to the kingdom, except the "violent battle for Christ" was now required)?

Comment: 1) Take analogy: soldiers have old weapons and cannot attack enemy by such. Thus they are ordered just to hold enemy by battling him valiantly with old weapons. Now, their children are given super-powerful new weapons and ordered to fight valiantly in attacking enemy and destroying him. In both cases there is valiant fight through usage of the weapons, first with old, then with new. The old soldiers are awarded with the same laurels for their preparation of and participation in victory, for they fought in the same war, similarly valiantly, yet with older weaponry, but it is one fight, one war.

Comment: 2) The second question is answered by the "1)": "and it did not require to 'valiantly battle for Christ'", but I have not said this, prophets fought most valiantly with the "weapons", that is to say, intensity of divine Grace available for them. That intensity and prophets' valiant co-action with it was not enough to destroy the power of sin and death, but still was necessary for preparation of humanity for the acceptance of the "new weaponry" - the intensity of Grace through the Lord's Incarnation, through which the war against sin and death was won, but the same war was going on in OT times.

Comment: I am afraid your analogy doesn’t quite reflect the case we are looking at. You say that "In both cases there is valiant fight" and that "the old soldiers … fought in the same war, similarly valiantly", but Jesus said that the violence with regard to the kingdom had been there only since the days of John the Baptist.

Comment: I'll trim up it for you: the "law and prophets before John" means that before John saints of the OT put their efforts only to resist sin; but with Jesus' Advent the saints of the NT can not only resist, but also attack and defeat sin. In both cases there is an effort/fight on the part of saints by means of the different intensities of divine Grace: a) the resistive  effort/fight and b) the attacking/defeating effort, the second one is specifically called even "violence", but it is one war, for prophets resisted sin in expectation of Advent of the one through whom humans would even defeat sin.

Comment: (1) Why are you talking about defeating sin in the first place? Didn’t we talk about taking and entering the kingdom instead? After all, Jesus didn’t say “from the days of John the sin is being defeated by violence, and the violent defeat it by force”. Jesus wasn’t speaking here about sin at all! He was speaking about the kingdom. Are you sure you are not substituting one thing for another? I understand that defeating sin and entering the kingdom are closely related, yet they are not one and the same thing.

Comment: (2) It looks like in your perspective the right of entering the kingdom for each individual starting from the days of John the Baptist is based on whether he or she defeats the sin – something that the previous warriors couldn’t do because the old weapons didn’t have that capacity. However, when does the sin get defeated? Can we really claim that even one New Testament saint has died having reached the condition of absolute sinlessness? Of course not!

Comment: (3) The absolute defeat of sin will happen when the death and the hell are finally cast into the lake of fire in Rev. 20:14, or a bit earlier at the battle led by the One who sits on the horse and His army in Rev 19:19, or at least at the Lord’s return when the dead saints are resurrected and the living saints’ bodies are transfigured in 1st Cor 15:50-58, that is, made glorious and sinless.

Comment: (4) By your logic then, only those saints who will be living at the Lord’s return will have the right to enter the kingdom because from among all the warriors using the new weapon only they will, in fact, be the ones who will use that weapon according to its real capacity and purpose, that is, they will finally defeat the sin. And all the other saints who have died prior to that, according to this logic, won’t have the right to enter into the kingdom because they didn’t actually defeat the sin.

Comment: (5) Also, while the ultimate defeat of sin is something pertaining to the future, the Lord did not use the future tense when He spoke about taking the kingdom. He was using the present tense instead: “the kingdom of heaven suffers violence, and the violent TAKE it by force” (Mt. 11:12), “the publicans and the harlots GO into the kingdom of God before you” (Mt. 21:31).

Comment: 1) "defeating sin" and "entering the kingdom" are not just closely related, the first is necessary, the sine qua non for the second.They are not identical as, say, "contest" and "victory" are not identical in sports, but the second is impossible without the first. Similarly, unless one fights against sin when this opportunity is given to him by Jesus' advent, he will not inherit the Kingdom, not God's one, to be sure.

Comment: 2) "Absolute sinlessness" is difficult notion needing a semantic precision. If you mean in "sinlessness" lack of any imperfection, then that pertains only to God and even the highest of the saints are in a dynamic growth towards divine perfection, infinitely. If in "ab..e sin...ss" you mean healing of human nature from the consequences of Adam's sin and abolition of the sin-based death - the mark of this condition, then this sin can be defeated by repentance and acceptance of Christ's healing Grace working in us, through our co-working. This co-working with Grace can be called also "fight".

Comment: 3) Paul calls Christians "saints"  meaning that they are participating in the Kingdom, yet, they are not of course totally sinless, for even Paul says that "among sinners I am the first". As a rusty metal piece thrown in the fire that gradually melts it into a glowing fiery stuff, but this piece already is engulfed by the cleansing fire, so a repenting sinner is engulfed by the cleansing fire of Grace, that gradually consumes his sins through his co-action, transforming him into the "new creation".Christ's presence in us=His Kingdom's presence in us, Him being the principle of His Kingdom.

Comment: 4) Christ works in all saints with a different intensity, depending on the intensity and initiative of their own devotion and openness to His Infinity, so a saint, say, Ahmad, will have no advantage over St. Anthony (4th c.) in His Second Coming. Jesus' presence in saints before His Second Advent is no less real and emphatic as in His Second Coming, and all have to defeat power of sin in the same fight. Time and history goes on, but this fight against one's sins, the law of Satan's egotism in order to inherit life of Triniarian love (a.k.a. "Kingdom") remains absolutely the same in all epochs.

Comment: 5) When you accept Christ's salvific work in your heart and devote your life to co-work with it, to fight your sins, flaws, imperfections, frailty in order to get gradually "dressed" in the gifts of Holy Spirit, that should happen in your only historical life, for there is no other time. And your historical life is as dignified in the eyes of Lord as that of those who will be alive at His Second Advent. Again: it is impossible for Jesus to be present in your heart without Father and Spirit, and this presence is Kingdom in you, for Trinity is either greater to His Kingdom or equal to it.

Comment: P.s. These are difficult, spiritual questions, thanks for rising them, for what can be more pleasurable and beneficial at the same time than discussing them. Yet, this site does not encourage such long discussions unless they are moved to "chat" option. We can do that, or you can write to me by e-mail your very interesting questions: lgigineishvili@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the background of the end of the Torah and the prophets is vividly described in the prophets themselves as what God himself will do at the advent of the messianic age. Note that the first verse refers to John's mikveh (IE: "baptism"):

> [Zec 13:1-6 NET] 1 "In that day [IE: In the time of the messiah] there will be a fountain [IE: "living water" or rather "flowing water"] opened up for the dynasty of David [John baptized Jesus in water to fulfill this prophecy] and the people of Jerusalem to cleanse them from sin and impurity. 2 And also on that day," says the LORD who rules over all, "I will remove the names of the idols from the land and they will never again be remembered. **Moreover, I will remove the prophets and the unclean spirit from the land. 3 Then, if anyone prophesies in spite of this, his father and mother to whom he was born will say to him, 'You cannot live, for you lie in the name of the LORD.' Then his father and mother to whom he was born will run him through with a sword when he prophesies. 4 "Therefore, on that day each prophet will be ashamed of his vision when he prophesies and will no longer wear the hairy garment of a prophet to deceive the people. 5 Instead he will say, 'I am no prophet - indeed, I am a farmer, for a man has made me his indentured servant since my youth.' 6 Then someone will ask him, 'What are these wounds on your chest?' and he will answer, 'Some that I received in the house of my friends.'**
>
> [Dan 9:24 KJV] 24 Seventy weeks are determined upon thy people and upon thy holy city, to finish the transgression, and to make an end of sins, and to make reconciliation for iniquity, and to bring in everlasting righteousness, and to seal up the vision **and prophecy**, and to anoint the most Holy.
>
> [Heb 1:1-2 KJV] 1 God, who at sundry times and in divers manners **spake in time past unto the fathers by the prophets**, 2 Hath in these last days spoken unto us by [his] Son, whom he hath appointed heir of all things, by whom also he made the worlds;

The reason that prophets ceased is that the king had arrived. The time of shadows was over.

Instead, during the last days of the Jewish covenants God would pour out his spirit upon all flesh and they would prophesy:

> [Act 2:16-21 KJV] 16 But **this is that** which was spoken by the prophet Joel; 17 And it shall come to pass **in the last days**, saith God, I will pour out of my Spirit upon all flesh: **and your sons and your daughters shall prophesy, and your young men shall see visions, and your old men shall dream dreams: 18 And on my servants and on my handmaidens I will pour out in those days of my Spirit; and they shall prophesy**: 19 And I will shew wonders in heaven above, and signs in the earth beneath; blood, and fire, and vapour of smoke: 20 The sun shall be turned into darkness, and the moon into blood, before that great and notable day of the Lord come: 21 And it shall come to pass, [that] whosoever shall call on the name of the Lord shall be saved.

Comment: "Seventy weeks are determined upon thy people to finish the transgression ... and the prophesy" - Are you trying to say that those 70 weeks have already passed?

Comment: To be honest, I never speak about Daniel because I have not personally meditated thru the passage for myself, so if you are particularly concerned about a passage of Daniel, post it and I'll search it out. But I presume so because all the prophets spoke of Peter's day: [Act 3:24 KJV] 24 Yea, and all the prophets from Samuel and those that follow after, as many as have spoken, have likewise foretold of these days.

Comment: However, this guy has written a couple of books on Daniel from this viewpoint and he has produced many relevant videos which are available free here: http://donkpreston.com/about/prestons-videos-by-category/  The view is called "preterism" in case you want to research it.

Comment: Also, Gina who is a member here has tons of stuff on her excellent site: https://shreddingtheveil.org/

Comment: @brilliant  Ah, here is the best link:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MW-lobP4Qks&list=PLhTk2RamIg8s0Si21EzN8tF0ZM9wk51Vv

Answer (score 0):

"For ALL Prophets and the law prophesied until John". The prophesying of the old Prophets and the types and shadows of the Mosaic Law Covenant covered a time period (an Age) until the time of John, which is also the time of Jesus, not later. These prophesies include all of Daniel's, Ezekiel's, Jeremiah's, Isaiah's and all others including the "minor" prophets. All these prophesied until John's generation in the 1st Century "upon whom the END of the world (age)are come". What was it all these prophesied about: the coming of a messiah and the terrible, dark and deadly "Day of the Lord".

Comment: Hi Marcelo, welcome to BH.SE - thanks for contributing! This feels like the foundation of a great answer, and I suspect it could be expanded to give a more thorough explanation and justification for your reasoning. Please do take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get a chance, to learn more about the site and how it all works.